# Find path for parent folder

Tags: c, string, strncpy

I'm trying to parse a string in c something like this :

```
/afolder/secondfolder/thirdone
```

do a function and that function should return this:

```
/afolder/secondfolder
```

I've tryed many things...

```
int getParentFolder(const char *pPathNewLink, char* TargetDirectory) {

    char *dirPath = strrchr(pPathNewLink, '/');

    strncpy(TargetDirectory, pPathNewLink, dirPath - pPathNewLink);

    return 1;
}
```

I cannot use operating systems libraries. I got to do it that way.

I tryed calling the function like this :

```
char * test;
getParentFolder("/var/lib",test);
printf("%s", test);
```

but I get a seg fault...

Comment: Your code works for me. It do exactly what you say. Show the code which call this function, it can call it wrong.

Comment: @JIghtuse I can the function like this :  
char* targetFolder;
getParentFolder(pDirName, targetFolder);

Comment: Have you allocate memory for TargetDirectory?

Comment: @starrify Do I have to do it inside the function or outside just declaring and char*?

Comment: Did you null terminate `TargetDirectory`? You also didn't allocate the space for it.  Both will cause problems sooner or later (not allocating sooner than not null terminating).

Comment: You haven't posted your working code. Here the function name defined is "getParentFolder" but you are calling "GetDirFromPath". Post your original code on which you are working.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes this this is also what I suspect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the reason is that you haven't allocate memory for `test`.
Since you're trying to `strncpy` to `TargetDirectory`, it must be initialized and have a memory region.

Try:

```
char *test = malloc(256);
/* or this */
char test[256];
```

Then do your things like:

```
GetDirFromPath("/var/lib",test);
printf("%s", test);
```

Also, if you choose the `malloc` one, don't forget to free it after use:

```
free(test);
```

**EDITED:**

Also there's another problem, sorry for didn't see it at first.
To copy the first part of the string you use `strncpy`, however you still need to fill the ending `'\0'` of the string like this:

```
int getParentFolder(const char *pPathNewLink, char* TargetDirectory) {
    char *dirPath = strrchr(pPathNewLink, '/');
    strncpy(TargetDirectory, pPathNewLink, dirPath - pPathNewLink);
    TargetDirectory[dirPath - pPathNewLink] = 0; // please make sure there is enough space in TargetDirectory
    return 1;
}
```

Please let me know if there's still any problem.

Comment: You have to use this. Or you have to define "test" as a char "test[256]". Even if now you get a SegFault, then there must be something else causing it.

Comment: @Lorac Yes there _is_ something else. Please see my edited answer.